# Can I get sudo privilege while using vim?

Tags: linux, vim, sudo

So this happened a lot to me. I try to write a file that needs `sudo` privilege, but I didn't add `sudo` beforehand.

For example, this time, the file is located in `/Library/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/org.jabref.jabref.json` and it apparently needs sudo privilege to edit it. Anyhow, I don't know that, so I type `vim Library/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/org.jabref.jabref.json` to create and edit the `jabref.json` file, after the editing, I tried to save the file only get a `"can't open file for writing"` error.

I have to quit vim and start all over again. Is it possible to grant vim sudo privilege while I have already opened a vim editor in my terminal?

Comment: Try this command: `:w !sudo tee %`

Comment: There's a plugin: https://github.com/chrisbra/SudoEdit.vim

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
:w /tmp/jxhyc.json
:! sudo cp /tmp/jxhyc.json /Library/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/org.jabref.jabref.json
```

You should also be able to configure Vim to warn you when opening a read-only file and to show `[RO]` in the Vim status line.

Comment: It's a new file though. I think it is the folder itself that needs to be granted priviledge

Comment: Then I would use something like `:! sudo chmod go+w /Library/Google/Chrome/N*Hosts` followed by `:w`.  For me, it is always better to save to `/tmp` rather than abandoning any significant number of edits. You can *always* then exit to the shell, fix permissions etc and copy edited stuff over the top of the original file.